# Visio: Accessing Custom Color Variant from macro?

Tags: vba, visio

I created a custom color set in Visio 2016 but cannot access it from a macro. Even the *recorded* macro below errors out with:

```
Run-time error '-2032465751 (86db08a9)':


Invalid parameter.
```

The debugger highlights the line with 65535 in it. Any ideas how to pull this off using a macro?  Thanks!

```
Sub Macro3()

    'Enable diagram services
    Dim DiagramServices As Integer
    DiagramServices = ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled
    ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = visServiceVersion140 + visServiceVersion150

    ActivePage.SetTheme 33, 33, 33, 33, 33

    ActivePage.SetTheme ActivePage.GetTheme(visThemeTypeIndex), 65535, ActivePage.GetTheme(visThemeTypeEffect), ActivePage.GetTheme(visThemeTypeConnector), ActivePage.GetTheme(visThemeTypeFont)

    'Restore diagram services
    ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = DiagramServices

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**
Here's a working code example for others. Use PrintMasterGuids to find the GUID (the number in curly braces).

```
Public Sub PrintMasterGuids()
    '// Use this to find the master GUID for a custom color variant.
    Dim mst As Master
    Dim vDoc As Document
    'Change ThisDocument to the target if you're
    'not running the code from the same place
    Set vDoc = ThisDocument
    For Each mst In vDoc.Masters
        Debug.Print mst.NameU, mst.UniqueID
    Next
End Sub
Sub Theme_Office_with_Custom_colors()

    'Enable diagram services
    Dim DiagramServices As Integer
    DiagramServices = ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled
    ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = visServiceVersion140 + visServiceVersion150

    Dim UndoScopeID1 As Long
    UndoScopeID1 = Application.BeginUndoScope("Apply Theme to Document")

    Dim doc As Visio.Document
    Set doc = Visio.ActiveDocument

     '// Loop through pages:
    For Each pg In doc.Pages
        '// Office theme
        pg.SetTheme 33, 33, 33, 33, 33

        '// Apply the Custom colors
        Dim UndoScopeID2 As Long
        UndoScopeID2 = Application.BeginUndoScope("Apply Theme Variant")
        pg.PageSheet.CellsU("ColorSchemeIndex").FormulaU = "=USE({76B4C447-0406-0000-8E40-00608CF305B2})*0+65535"
        Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID2, True
    Next

    Application.EndUndoScope UndoScopeID1, True
    'Restore diagram services
    ActiveDocument.DiagramServicesEnabled = DiagramServices

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't use a custom color set directly with the api, so you've got to dip down and address the relevant cell directly.

When you create a custom color set Visio creates a separate (hidden) master to store the RGBs.  This master is assigned a GUID and you have to use this inside a `USE` function in the `ColorSchemeIndex` cell.

So in your code, if the only thing you want to change is the color cell then you could do this:

```
ActivePage.PageSheet.CellsU("ColorSchemeIndex").FormulaU = "=USE({007C1AB0-0002-0000-8E40-00608CF305B2})*0+65535"
```

...where the GUID is a reference to your master.

To get hold of the GUID in the first place, just apply your custom color set to the page and then inspect the `ColorSchemeIndex` cell formula, or, you could loop through the masters in your document and report the .UniqueID property as described here: http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2013/10/customizing-themes-in-visio-2013.html